# Downgrade from Windows 7 Ultimate to Home Premium?

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, product-key, downgrade

A few months ago, I acquired a Windows 7 Ultimate product key and updated from Home Premium to Ultimate. Well, now I get the "This copy of Windows is not genuine" message. I have the Home Premium product key that I was using before I upgraded to Ultimate. I would want to know how I could downgrade from Ultimate to Home Premium without having any CD and only the product key. If it helps, it's a 64-bit OS. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you “acquire” the key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a disk for doing this. Google for `digital river windows 7 iso` and download the ISO, use a tool called [ei.cfg Removal Utility](http://code.kliu.org/misc/winisoutils/) to change the ISO to Home Premium.

Now run the Tool [Windows 7 Downgrader](http://mp7000.deviantart.com/art/Windows-7-Enterprise-Downgrade-159805048) (read the comments there for special steps on 64bit systems),

[image]

click on "Downgrade to Home Premium", insert the Windows 7 DVD and do an [Inplace Upgrade/ Repair Installation](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html):

- In the running Windows 7, mount the ISO or insert the DVD
- Run setup from the DVD and select "Upgrade"

This downgrades Win7 Ultimate to Home Premium.

*NOTE: This is not officially supported by MS, but it works.*