# Installing Windows 7 Home on an existing Windows Professional

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-installation, reinstall, downgrade

I leave my workplace soon, and I have the opportunity to buy my computer. Whether it is a good idea or not, that's up to me, but what I am interested in is to keep my data, softwares, preferences, etc. I want to precise that there is no critical data on the computer and I can safely get it out of my workplace, there is nothing wrong with it.

The version of Windows that we have is a Professional license, where I need to be connected once in a while to the network in order for it to work. I would like to downgrade to Windows Home Premium.

The IT guys tell me that they have to do a complete re-installation of Windows, thus losing all my data/softwares. This solution does not suit me at all and I am in search of an alternative.

I have found [this superuser thread](https://superuser.com/q/538828/628659), but I guess the IT guys will be reluctant to use a non-supported software (official policy, blah blah).

Can I follow those steps:

1) Run the Windows Home installation disc and choose "Upgrade" and let the magic happen.

OR

2) Run the Windows Home installation disc and choose "Custom" and install on the Windows Professional partition. I have read that Windows will rename the existing Windows version *windows.old*, it will be unusable, but all the registry keys will remain. Am I wrong ?

Of course, the IT guys will do a complete clone of the drive, in case anything goes wrong.

Thanks a lot for your answers,

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/converting-from-windows-7-pro-to-home-premium/387e57f5-63e6-419c-aec5-1a28339c262c) would be useful to you. it contains some guidelines as well as some suggestions for the procedure.

Is there any particular reason why you'd like to downgrade the OS?

I'd also suggest to perform a backup and do a fresh install of the OS and all applications with it as this way you would avoid any potential compatibility issues and driver problems. You don't have to format the whole drive for this, just the boot partition (C drive).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link. I would rather not do anything about the OS, but apparently it is not possible, according to the IT guys. And yes, they will clone the disk, so the back up problem is solved.

Comment: If this is the case then either go for the fresh install and restore all the applications or simply try the guide on in the link. :) 
Post back with the results when you are done.